# How can i avoid Location service in AlAssetLibrary? Can i retrieve files using AlAssetLibrary without using Location Service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, libraries, alasset

i created a application to get images from iPhone photo Folder using ALAssetLibrary.
 Can i retrieve files using AlAssetLibrary without using  Location Service? 
How can i avoid Location service in AlAssetLibrary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to access ALAssetLibrary without using location services. You have to use the, much more limited, UIImagePickerController to get around that problem.

Comment: Is this still the case (Feb 2012)?

Comment: @BradSmith See my answer below, not sure if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is incorrect if you only need one image from the library.  For example, if you are having the user choose a photo to upload.  In this case you can get that single image with ALAssetLibrary, without needing Location permissions.

To do this, use a UIImagePickerController to select the picture; you just need the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`, which the UIImagePickerController provides.

This has the benefit of giving you access to an unmodified `NSData` object, which you can then upload.

This is helpful because re-encoding the image later using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` can double the size of your file!

To present the picker:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To get the image and/or data:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSURL *imageURL = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [assetLibrary assetForURL:imageURL
                  resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                      // get your NSData, UIImage, or whatever here
                     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [self defaultRepresentation];
                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage]];

                     Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
                     NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
                     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

                     if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
                         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
                     }
                 }
                 failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
                     // Something went wrong; get the image the old-fashioned way                            
                     // (You'll need to re-encode the NSData if you ever upload the image)
                     UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                     if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
                         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
                     }
                 }];
}
```