# How can i avoid location service from AlassetLibrary?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, alasset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i avoid Location service in AlAssetLibrary? Can i retrieve files using AlAssetLibrary without using Location Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702505/how-can-i-avoid-location-service-in-alassetlibrary-can-i-retrieve-files-using-al)

Hi all,
 I am a newbie in iphone development and obj-c. i am using "ALAssetLibrary" in my Application to retrieve images from Photo Library.
I identified that "**ALAssetPropertyLocation**"Property Key only available if location services are enabled for the caller. it is the key to retrieve the location information of the asset.But i am not using "ALAssetPropertyLocation"Property.i am using only **ALAssetPropertyURLs.**

whenever i am trying to deploy my Application in a new device there is a message box with the message "Location Service needed.."
can i able to hide the "ALAssetPropertyLocation"Property?

I would really appreciate if someone could assist me in the correct way to approach my problem, and if possible any sample code to get my started.

Thank You In Advance :)

**this is my Code:**

```
//Getting image url from dictionary according to the user input
NSURL *imageurl = [dict objectForKey: [youSaid text]];   

//Getting asset from url
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);    
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    //Setting asset image to image view according to the image url
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref]];        
};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Error, cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
}; 

if(imageurl != nil)
{
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLibrary assetForURL:imageurl resultBlock:resultblock    failureBlock:failureblock];      
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

enabling "location services "is a requirement for using the AssetsLibrary.
The reason is that any photos/videos in the Photo-Library might contain geodata. This data is not just available through ALAssetPropertyURLs, but also if you read out the raw data from the asset (by using the getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: Method of ALAssetsRepresentation). Cause there is no way to strip the geo metadata from the raw image data (in case location services are disabled), I guess the design decision was made to make "location services" mandatory for using the AssetsLibrary.

This requirement might be confusing to the user. So you need to do 2 things:

1) If the user denies access to location services, then present a clear message while your app needs this access and that the app does not actually determine the current position or any GPS/data.

2) Display clear instructions how to enable location services, once the user has pressed "NO" on the initial dialog.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: Location Services mandatory for what seems like the ONLY way to access photos url/paths? This is sadistic.